# Factorization of a joint density over a directed graph

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, self-study, graphical-model

Let $G = (V,E)$  be a directed acyclic graph.

Let $i \rightarrow j$  be an edge such that the parents of $j$  are exactly:

- the parents of $i$,
- and $i$.

Let $L\left(G \right)$  be the set defined by {a vertex and its parents, for all vertices in $G$}

Let $G' = (V,F)$  where $F$  is $E$  with $j \rightarrow i$ instead of $i \rightarrow j$.

Given a set of random variables $(X_{v})_{v \in V}$  for which the joint density can be factorized over $L\left(G \right)$, I would like to show that the joint density could also be factorized over $L\left(G' \right)$.

---

Let $P$ be the parents of $i$ in the graph $G$, thus the parents of $j$ in the graph $G'$.

So I would like to show that there exists $g_{i}$ and $g_{j}$ such that: $g_{i}(x_{i},x_{j},x_{P}) \times g_{j}(x_{j},x_{P}) = f_{i}(x_{i},x_{P}) \times f_{j}(x_{i},x_{j},x_{P})$.

I am unsure whether I could just consider that there was a swap of $i$ and $j$, and I could take $g_{i}=f_{j}$ and $g_{j}=f_{i}$. Or maybe, there is something to do with conditional probabilities and Bayes formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is termed a **covered edge reversal**, which preserves Markov equivalence of directed acyclic graphs. A proof of equivalence is given in Lemma 1 of *[A Transformational Characterization of Equivalent Bayesian Network Structures](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/65664/uai95.pdf)*, by Max Chickering. The relationship between Markov properties and factorisation is well established in the theory of graphical models, for example [Theorem 5.14](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=G_4E_w_wJzcC&lpg=PA74&vq=DF&pg=PA74#v=onepage&q=Theorem%205.14&f=false) of *Probabilistic Networks and Expert Systems*.

Comment: This is the perfect answer, I realize now that I was getting lost with my own proof. :)